# Is there any way to check whether a google map polygon or circle area is greater than the earth hemisphere

Tags: mongodb, google-maps

Is there any way to check whether a google map polygon or circle area is greater than the earth hemisphere so that we can know the geowithin queries will not work properly in mongo queries [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/).Or what is the condition where the geo spatial query works perfect.

```
{
   <location field>: {
      $geoWithin: {
         $geometry: {
            type: <"Polygon" or "MultiPolygon"> ,
            coordinates: [ <coordinates> ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For egs: Area of a polygon can be calculated by:

`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(e.getPath())`

where e is the event object varible when the polygon completed event. but how can we compare those with the earth hemisphere area?

Answer (score 1):

> how can we compare those with the earth hemisphere area?

Provided that the [Earth radius is about 6371 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius), you can just calculate the spherical surface area of the hemisphere:

```
A = 2πr^2
A = 2π(6371)^2 
A = 255032236 square km
```

If the result of `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(e.getPath())` is greater than the above value, then the area polygon/circle is greater than one of the Earth's hemisphere.

Comment: Thanks man. I have already done that, but the geo spatial query doesn't return results.

Comment: Hi, either you update your question with example documents, example queries, expected output, MongoDB version OR you open a new question.

Comment: My question is when to use custom crs object in mongo geoWothin query?